# GitKraken make message with git hook

Tags: githooks, gitkraken

**Is it possible to make a message in GitKraken so the developer sees if the git hook manipulated his commit ?**

I write git hooks where some files are not allowed to be send to the server and reset them in the commit. How can I make this visible to the developer in GitKraken ? It would be very bad if he does not see that a file which he commited was not commited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated gitkraken this morning to v3.3.1 and, now it dislpay when push failed due to an error in pre-receive hook, or others hooks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible.

It's a known issue in GK that when a server-side pre-receive hook declines commits (e.g. when direct pushes to certain branches are forbidden), the pushing deveoper nonetheless receives a `Push Successful` message in GK. Seeing that, I do not expect GK to react to any other hooks in this state of development.

As you might expect by my evasive phrasing, I can not provide secure evidence for the general case.

UPDATE:
GitKraken does support hooks from version [3.2.0](https://support.gitkraken.com/release-notes/current) and the questionable behaviour I described above is a thing of the past!